# Waitforsingleobject is decreasing my program perfomance

Tags: python-3.x, performance, waitforsingleobject

I have tested the same code in python in two diferent computers. In the first one the code is 9s longer and in the second one(a more powerfull machine with 16MRAM x 8MRAM of first one) is 185s longer. Analising in cProfile, the most critical process in both case is the waitforsingleobject. Analisyng a specific function, i can see that the critical part is the OCR with tesserecat. why so diferrent perfomance in this two machines?

The main lines from cProfile of this specific function is:

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

1    0.002    0.002  115.398  115.398 bpl-Redonda4.py:261(pega_stack_nome_jogadores)

18    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 pytesseract.py:106(prepare)

18    0.000    0.000    0.118    0.007 pytesseract.py:116(save_image)

18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pytesseract.py:140(subprocess_args)

18    0.000    0.000  115.186    6.399 pytesseract.py:162(run_tesseract)

18    0.001    0.000  115.373    6.410 pytesseract.py:199(run_and_get_output)

12    0.000    0.000   76.954    6.413 pytesseract.py:295(image_to_string)

12    0.000    0.000   76.954    6.413 pytesseract.py:308()

6    0.000    0.000   38.419    6.403 pytesseract.py:328(image_to_boxes)

6    0.000    0.000   38.419    6.403 pytesseract.py:345()

18    0.000    0.000    0.060    0.003 pytesseract.py:97(cleanup)

18    0.000    0.000  115.096    6.394 subprocess.py:979(wait)

18  115.096    6.394  115.096    6.394 {built-in method_winapi.WaitForSingleObject}

Comment: You ran some code we can't see and on one machine it ran 9 seconds longer than something and on another machine it ran 185 seconds longer than something else (?) and you hope we can help? Please try to pose your question more clearly else nobody will be able to help. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the code spends 9s with a computer I7-8550 1.8Ghz, 8GbRAM,Windows 10 Single Lenguage, Python 3.7 and Tesseract 4.0. The other one spends 185s with a computer Intel Xeon CPU e5-1607v2 3GHz, 16GB RAM , Windows 10 Pro, Python 3.7 and Tesseract 4.0. The code has 1k lines, but fundamentally it tries recognize  texts and numbers from a program, using pytesseract.

Comment: Is your code using multiprocessing ?  It seems that a main program synchronizes with child worker processes.